# How to implement filters in Eventhub?

Tags: azure-eventhub

In my application, various events published to a Eventhub. But my consumer group needs only specific set of events. How to filter this in Eventhub?

Comment: You cannot. See the answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34003971/route-events-to-eventhub-eventprocessor) question

Comment: Thanks @PeterBons . I get it.

Comment: If you use eventgrid, you may be able to filter events ? check this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-grid-event-hubs-integration

Answer (score 2):

Following this [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/474b7eaf-a607-4e25-88b9-f7f1b034d36e/can-messages-from-azure-event-hub-be-filtered-to-this-level?forum=servbus):

> event hubs doesn't support filtering as subscriptions on a topic for example and it's due to performance and thorughput reasons that need to be maximazed to have million events/sec for the ingestion system.

As @Sapnandu mentioned, you can use Azure Service Bus for this, or you can implement a filter yourself using [Event Processor Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-event-processor-host)

For instance - when using the [node module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/event-processor-host) for EPH:

```
const onMessage = async (context, data) => {
  // use data to get message payload (data.body) and implement a filter here
  // suggestion: create an event name field for each message and query it here
};

const onError = (error) => {
  // do something with it
};

await eph.start(onMessage, onError);
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventhub don't have any filter concept. You should use service Bus for filter the data after EventHub.