# Trigger Azure function by Azure event hub containing some user property

Tags: azure-functions, azure-eventhub, azure-triggers

Is it possible to have an Azure function that is triggered by a message on an Azure event hub ONLY if the EventData contains some specified user property in the Properties dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to control the trigger but you can control the processing based on the condition inside your function code.

Comment: Also, this topic may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29127648/should-event-hubs-be-split-on-message-type